# Are there any alternatives to PyInstaller for making standalone Python Executables or Linux Libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, performance

Everyone recommends pyinstaller, but I'd like to:

1. Create the C version of the python code (including all dependent modules). In a simple script.
2. Compile this C version into an executable or library.
3. Call it wherever I want. For example, on linux.
4. With this I want to gain more speed in the execution of the code because it will be compiled machine code and not interpreted.

A pseudo-code to example:

```py
import numpy as np

def print_hi(name):
    arr = np.zeros(9)
    print(arr)
    print(f'Hi, {name}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('Compiled Python')
```

I did a few searches but all of them landed on the PyInstaller option.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question exactly?  What do you mean by "Create the C version of the python code "?

Comment: The code example is bad example, because it is using C-compiled numpy library. Also, what is wrong with pyinstaller?

Comment: I've updated my question and added the answer to my question for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers. I found 2 methods:

**First method using Cython and gcc.**

- GCC v9.4.0
- Python v3.11
- Cython v0.29.14

> Taking into account that the file name is "main.py".

Convert the python code into C code:

```
cython -3 --embed main.py -o main.c
```

Compile the C code into binary:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 `python-config3 --cflags` main.c -o main `python3-config --ldflags`
```

**Second method using Nuitka:**

- Nuitka v1.8.1

> 

```
nuitka --follow-imports --onefile main.py
```

**Then, finally**

```
./main.bin
```

And it outputs:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Hi, Compiled Python
```